# Openlayers Vector layer rendering coordinates outside typical boundaries

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, spatial

I started working on a Vector Layer to render SQL Spatial Data in OpenLayers. When rendering [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Nk2.png) example (see [Json](https://gist.github.com/fizzbuzz1337/0d5c48a966bc7b848a833ba0c2670d07?short_path=ffd62a9)) everything works perfectly fine. See code below:

```
    //creates source to get json data from
let vSource = new VectorSource({
  url: '/assets/germany.json',
  format: new GeoJSON()
});
//set focus of the camera on this source
vSource.on('addfeature', () => {
  this.map.getView().fit(vSource.getExtent());
  console.log(this.map.getView().getCenter());
});
//add source to layer and afterwards load it into map
let vLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vSource,
  visible: true
});
//layer styling
vLayer.setStyle(new Style({
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#FF5733',
    width: 8  
  })
}));
this.map.addLayer(vLayer);
```

Map instantiation looks as following:

```
this.map = new Map({
  view: new View({
    center: [10, 10],
    zoom: 3,
  }),
  layers: [],
  target: 'ol-map'
});
```

But when i want to render [this](https://gist.github.com/fizzbuzz1337/fee5c83e553be4f09b37a98d92152dc7?short_path=1a8bfa2) json file I am facing a blank map. Focus wont get set and not even errors appear. I am assuming its all about the boundaries?
How can Polygon coordinates get rendered which are our outside default boundaries, if there is such thing as "default"?

For example:

```
[12058.4521484375, 5345.98388671875],
[11408.95703125, 5345.98388671875]
```

Reading through the [API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html) I can deduce that the option `extent` may be key to solving this issue?

Best regards
A newbie at OpenLayers

Comment: y coordinates between -90 and +90 with x coordinate values outside -180 to +180 may suggest your polygon is in a wrapped world.  You would need `wrapX: false` as an option to the vector source constructor to see it.  If the y coordinate is outside that range you have a non-standard geojson which is using a custom projection.

Comment: So `wrapX` would be the solution in case of json data where only the x coordinates are out of the boundaries (tried it out and worked, thanks!), but how can I tackle the problem of custom projections? Is there a possiblity to create a VectorLayer which has a custom coordinate system(for example: minY: -inf, minX:-inf, maxY:+inf, maxX:+inf)?

Comment: A GeoJSON using custom projection coordinates should contain a crs entry as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-test.html but sometimes they don't and you just have to make a best guess.

Comment: Oh ok, well thats not the case in my json data :/.  Do you know an answer to
`Is there a possiblity to create a VectorLayer which has a custom coordinate system(for example: minY: -inf, minX:-inf, maxY:+inf, maxX:+inf)?`

Comment: It is possible, for example there might be a polar projection where the opposite pole is infinite in all direction.

Answer (score 0):

Openlayers default projection is EPSG:3857. I think your geojson and center of map is EPSG:4326.

```
this.map = new Map({
  view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [10, 10],
    zoom: 3,
  }),
  layers: [],
  target: 'ol-map'
});

let vSource = new VectorSource({
  url: '/assets/germany.json',
  format: new GeoJSON({ featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am not sure why projection should be the solution in this case? Furthermore changing the projection doesnt change anything.m Note that we are talking, in this case, about coordinates that are outside default boundaries (take a look at these [this](https://gist.github.com/fizzbuzz1337/fee5c83e553be4f09b37a98d92152dc7?short_path=1a8bfa2) coordinates.)

Comment: The center and zoom will be reset when `map.getView().fit()` is called

Comment: How could be a point coordinates like these in EPSG:4326; 20527.55859375, 43.88205730390537?

Comment: @emincankirmizi
 It is Italy on a wrapped world https://gist.github.com/fizzbuzz1337/fee5c83e553be4f09b37a98d92152dc7  Click on Raw to see the coordinates

Comment: @Mike I know that `fit()` will override the current state of zoom and view position, thats not the issue.